# According to chat, Meta Stack Exchange was born today!

Tags: support, bug, chat, meta

I noticed today [this chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1701/meta-stack-exchange) here on Meta Stack Exchange chat domain.

The room has been automatically created yesterday. This is the standard protocol for **new sites**, e.g. see [this transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1888/2011/11/30), it's from over 11 years ago when Movies.SE was launched, and got a default chat room. Text is 100% the same.

Can anyone explain what is going on? Misclick of a button by a developer?

Comment: Notice the different servers. The chat room was created on Meta's server.

Comment: @Andreasd well yes, I said that clearly that the new room is here, in MSE. What you mean different? Different servers from what?

Comment: Automatically created chat rooms get put on the other server, not this. Also, the text is similar, but not exactly the same. There’s a part missing in the new room. So, this is indeed peculiar.